# jquery, add div with class definition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, addition

So I see here [how to add a div](http://api.jquery.com/add/)  and here [how to add a class](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) but I'm having trouble combining the two.  I want to generate a whole bunch of div's with a specific class and id within the div sparkLineContainer.

I have the containing div

```
<div id="#sparkLineContainer"></div>
```

and I want to add a bunch of the following to it

```
    <div id="#sparkLineContainer">
        <div class="sparkLines" id="id1">Some stuff here</div>
        <div class="sparkLines" id="id2">Some stuff here</div>
        <div class="sparkLines" id="id3">Some stuff here</div>
// and so on
    </div>
```

snippet - I didn't make it very far, I'm stumped

```
$('#sparkContainer').add("div");  \\ How do I add the id and class to this div?
                                  \\ And as a repeat the function will it overwrite this?
```

The function I'm trying to do this with.

```
function renderSparklines (array1, sparkLineName, id) {
// array1 is the data for the spark line
// sparkLineName is the name of the data.  
// Turn all array values into integers
arrayStringToInt(array1);

    // Create new div of class sparkLines
$('#sparkContainer').add("div")

    // Render new spark line to
$('.sparkLines').sparkline(array1, {width:'90px'});

var htmlString = "";  //  Content to be added to new div
//  GENERATE LITTLE SPARK BOX 
    htmlString += 
                '<font class = "blueDescriptor">' + sparkLineName + '</font>'+
                '<br>'+
                '<font class = "greyDescriptorSmall">Ship to Shore</font>'+
                '<br>'+
                '<font class = "blackDescriptorSparkLine">' + array1[array1.length-1] + '</font>'+
                '<font class = "greenDescriptorSparkline">(' + (array1[array1.length-1] - array1[array1.length-2]) + ')</font>' +
                '<br>';
    $('.sparkLines').prepend(htmlString);
```

}

Comment: .add() function doesn't add's a div. It just adds to the matched selector.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need `.append` or `.prepend` to add a div to the container. See my version below,

```
var $sparkLines = $('.sparkLines');
$("#sparkLineContainer")
   .append('<div id="id' + 
            ($sparkLines.length + 1) + 
            '" class="sparkLines">Some Stuff Here</div>')
```

Also I noticed that you have id of the div as `#sparkLineContainer`. You should change it as below,

```
<div id="sparkLineContainer"> 
...
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/KU4Ry/2/)

Comment: I used the same code but with my div names etc.  and no div was added to the content and no error either.

Comment: @rd42 Works for me http://jsfiddle.net/skram/KU4Ry/1/ . Also in the markup make sure to change the div ID to `sparkLineContainer` not `#sparkLineContainer'.

Comment: Thanks, I was just trying to JSFiddle it

Comment: I'm still futzing with it.  It works in jsfiddle but not in my code yet.  I'm still trying...

Answer (score 25):

`add` does not do what you think it does.  You are looking for `append` or something similar.

You can create the div first and define its attributes and contents, then append it:

```
var $newDiv = $("<div/>")   // creates a div element
                 .attr("id", "someID")  // adds the id
                 .addClass("someClass")   // add a class
                 .html("<div>stuff here</div>");

$("#somecontainer").append($newDiv);
```

Comment: I used the same code but with my div names etc.  and no div was added to the content and no error either.

Comment: All of the posted answer should work, if they don't then you're doing something wrong in applying them.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a div or any other tag along with class like:

`$('<div/>',{ class : 'example'}).appendTo("p");`

Answer (score 2):

Probably the easiest way is to just modify the innerHTML:

```
$("#sparkLineContainer").append('<div class="sparkLine" id="id1"></div>');
```

There's other ways as well, but this is the method I generally use.

Comment: Will replace the existing div contents inside #sparkLineContainer. No good!

Comment: Modified it to append. I was assuming it was empty at start.

Comment: I used the same code but with my div names etc.  and no div was added to the content and no error either.

Comment: Well in your code you have the container id as "#sparkLineContainer", when it should be just "sparkLineContainer". Not sure if that was a typo on SO though.