# How do I add class when appending ul with new li?

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#btn').click(function(){
            var toAdd = $('input[id=ListItem]').val();
            $('ul').append('<li>' + toAdd + '</li>');
            $('#ListItem').val('');
```

How would I go about adding a class to the newly created li?

Tried looking up a solution but didn't understand some of the solutions and the code was completely different then mine.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicated actually, [jquery, add div with class definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10283414/jquery-add-div-with-class-definition)

It's just HTML markup, you already has code to add `<li>` tag, you can add class to that tag

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#btn').click(function(){
            var toAdd = $('input[id=ListItem]').val();
            $('ul').append('<li class="class-1 class-2">' + toAdd + '</li>');
            $('#ListItem').val('');
```